# Flash CS6 - SWF file to communicate with the internet

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I have dynamic text that loads from a txt file that is hosted on my site. When I play the swf file I get a Flash Player security error: myfile.swf is trying to communicate with the Internet-enabled location: myurl.com. To let this application communicate with the Internet click Settings.

Is there a way to give permissions to myurl.com within flash - not in the flash player settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you launch swf localy? No, there isn't another way to give permissions, only by adding the folder with swf file (or any parent folder or the hole disk partition) to the trusted locations in flash player settings panel.

Comment: I am testing it locally but it's a banner ad and will eventually be published on someone else's site. I need to be able to change the text once it's live.

Comment: Permissions to access the data from remote url are required only locally, so you will no have this problem when you deploy this swf to server and open it by http. But be sure that your swf and server url have the same domain otherwise you will account the cross-domain issue will and have to add crossdomain.xml to your server.